Azure Service Bus throwing "There is already one downstream subscriber" error
We are getting following error when trying to start our application.
We have a ASB topic and one listener is listening to the topic.
ERROR ServiceBusReceiveLinkProcessor [boundedElastic-8]  -  - TRX_ID:  There is already one downstream subscriber

Anyone have idea of what is going wrong here?
We have max concurrent consumers as 5
Azure Service Bus version we used is 7.14.1

That does not appear to be an error from the Service Bus client library.  Please share the package name and full stack trace.

I could not get full stack trace, but this is where the issue occurs,
message":"\tat com.azure.messaging.servicebus.implementation.ServiceBusReceiveLinkProcessor.subscribe(ServiceBusReceiveLinkProcessor.java:319)
@JesseSquire

Can you share the code trying so far? @vasantharajan

I'd suggest opening an issue in the Azure SDK for Java repository.   This seems like something that will require deeper investigation rather than a quick answer on StackOverflow.  https://github.com/azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues
